# Attempt to read property "userID" on bool

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-9

I have a problem with Laravel 9 where the userID is showing bool error whenever I click on the delete, I ma keeping a list from where by using delete I can delete from the list but Attempt to read property "userID" on bool

This is my model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Doctor_review extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $primaryKey = 'doctorReviewID';
}
```

This is my controller portion

```
    $reviews = Doctor_review::all();
    return view('admin.docreviews')->with('doctor_reviews', $reviews);
}
public function deletereview(Request $request){
    $review = Doctor_review::where('doctorReviewID', $request->doctorReviewID)->first();
    return view('admin.docreviews')->with('doctor_reviews', $review);
}
public function deletereviewSubmit(Request $request){
    $review = Doctor_review::where('doctorReviewID', $request->doctorReviewID)->first();
    $review->delete();
    return redirect()->route('docreviews');
}
}
```

This is my blade page

```
@extends('layouts.appAdmin')
@section('contentAdmin')
    <table class = "table table-border">
        
        <tr>
            <th>Patient ID</th>
            <th>Doctor ID</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Rating</th>
        
        
        </tr>
        @foreach($doctor_reviews as $review)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$review->userID}}</td>
            <td>{{$review->doctorID}}</td>
            <td>{{$review->description}}</td>
            <td>{{$review->point}}</td>
            <td><a href="/deletereview/{{$review->doctorReviewID}}">Delete</a></td>
        
        </tr>
        @endforeach
@endsection
```

This is my delete form page

```
    <head>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
        <h2>Delete review</h2> 
            <form action="{{ route('deletereview') }}" method="POST">  
                
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <input type="hidden" name="doctorReviewID" value="{{review->doctorReviewID}}">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="userID">Patient ID</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userID" name="userID" placeholder="Enter Patient ID">
                   
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="doctorID">Doctor ID</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="doctorID" name="doctorID" placeholder="Enter Doctor ID">
                    
                </div>
               
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="description">Description</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="description" name="description" placeholder="description">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="point">Rating</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="point" name="point" placeholder="point">
                   
                </div>
              
                <div class="form-group p-1">
                    <span>
                        <input type="submit" name="Delete" value="Delete" class="btn btn-info">
                    </span>
                </div>
                </div>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add the full error message to your question and show us _exactly_ where (which file and point out on which line) the error is thrown. Just saying you get an error and then post multiple different code blocks without any further info requires us to read through it all and guess/assume where/what the issue is, which risks wasting both your and our time.

Comment: you are returning to same page with different variables in **deletereview** function and its above function. In deletereview function **first()** return first record and **all()** return collection/ array. To display data of return after using **all()** foreach loop is used but  **foreach** is not use when data return after using **first()** function. Please review your code

Comment: You can add @ like **{{ @$review->userID }}** with the variable to ignore the error and just review your code what is missing. Also post your question with details and error if you still have issues.

Answer (score 0):

your userID value is boolean, if you want to call with -> please make sure your userID is not boolean or null. You can do {{ dd($review->userID) }} in your blade to see the value of userID.

Comment: From the error message it seems his $review var is actually a bool.

Comment: if his $review is bool, it will return error trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0):

Without the full error message I can't really know for sure. But this is my guess:

```
return view('admin.docreviews')->with('doctor_reviews', $reviews);
```

This adds a list of reviews to the form, and when you foreach, you will loop through the list.

```
return view('admin.docreviews')->with('doctor_reviews', $review);
```

This will add a single review to the form, and when you foreach, you will loop through its properties.

```
return view('admin.docreviews')->with('doctor_reviews', [$review]);
```

Might fix your issue. But I'd suggest splitting the blade page into a list view page and a detail view page.

Answer (score 0):

In two functions you are returning to one view with different type of variables.
You are using **foreach loop** to read the both type of variables i.e. **collection and single value**.

```
    public function deletereview(Request $request){
        $review = Doctor_review::where('doctorReviewID', $request->doctorReviewID)->first();
         return view('admin.docreviews')->with('doctor_reviews', $review);
    }
```

**first()** will return element itself and can be in blade file as:

```
           {{$doctor_reviews->userID}}
```

And **all()** will return a [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-collections).

```
       $reviews = Doctor_review::all();
       return view('admin.docreviews')->with('doctor_reviews', $reviews);
```

To access data of collection **$review** in blade file loop is used i.e.:

```
           @foreach($doctor_reviews as $review)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$review->userID}}</td>
            <td>{{$review->doctorID}}</td>
            <td>{{$review->description}}</td>
            <td>{{$review->point}}</td>
            <td><a href="/deletereview/{{$review->doctorReviewID}}">Delete</a></td>
        
        </tr>
        @endforeach
```